# PySpark - Fillna specific rows based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I want to replace null values in a dataframe, but only on rows that match an specific criteria.

**I have this DataFrame:**

```
A|B   |C   |D   |
1|null|null|null|
2|null|null|null|
2|null|null|null|
2|null|null|null|
5|null|null|null|
```

**I want to do this:**

```
A|B   |C   |D   |
1|null|null|null|
2|x   |x   |x   |
2|x   |x   |x   |
2|x   |x   |x   |
5|null|null|null|
```

**My case**

So all the rows that have the number 2 in the column A should get replaced.

The columns A, B, C, D are dynamic, they will change in numbers and names.

I also want to be able to select all the rows, not only the replaced ones.

**What I tried**

I tried with df.where and fillna, but it does not keep all the rows.

I also though about doing with withColumn, but I only know the column A, all the others will change on each execution.

**Adapted Solution:**

```
 df.select("A",
             *[
                 when(col("A") == '2', 
                    coalesce(col(c),
                    lit('0').cast(df.schema[c].dataType))
                 ).otherwise(col(c)).alias(c) 
                 for c in cols_to_replace
               ])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pyspark.sql.functions.when`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) with [`pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, col, lit, when

cols_to_replace = df.columns[1:]
df.select(
    "A",
    *[
        when(col("A")==2, coalesce(col(c), lit("x"))).otherwise(col(c)).alias(c) 
        for c in cols_to_replace
     ]
).show()
#+---+----+----+----+
#|  A|   B|   C|   D|
#+---+----+----+----+
#|  1|null|null|null|
#|  2|   x|   x|   x|
#|  2|   x|   x|   x|
#|  2|   x|   x|   x|
#|  5|null|null|null|
#+---+----+----+----+
```

Inside the list comprehension, you check to see if the value of `A` is `2`. If yes, then you coalesce the value of the column and the literal `x`. This will replace `null`s with `x`. Otherwise, keep the same column value.

Comment: Incredible how fast you answered! I am just adding that I had problems with dataTypes. So in order to solve that, I replaced 'x' to 0 and used the dataframe schema to cast, to wherever type it is, from inside the coalesce.

Comment: df = (df.select("A",*[
                                              when(col("A") == '2', 
                                                   coalesce(col(c), lit('0').cast(df.schema[c].dataType))
                                                  ).otherwise(col(c)).alias(c) 
                                              for c in cols_to_replace
                                           ]))