# Fillna values for specific columns and specific rows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following pyspark DataFrame:

```py
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([
    StructField('user', StringType(), True),
    StructField('created', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('month_1', FloatType(), True),
    StructField('month_2', FloatType(), True),
    StructField('month_3', FloatType(), True),
    StructField('month_4', FloatType(), True),
  ])

data = [['tom', 2, np.nan,1.0,1.0,1.0], 
        ['nick', 1,1.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
        ['jack', 3,np.nan,np.nan,1.0,1.0],
        ['jason', 2,np.nan,1.0,1.0,np.nan]]

df=spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)

df.show()

+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| user|created|month_1|month_2|month_3|month_4|
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  tom|      2|    NaN|    1.0|    1.0|    1.0|
| nick|      1|    1.0|    NaN|    NaN|    NaN|
| jack|      3|    NaN|    NaN|    1.0|    1.0|
|jason|      2|    NaN|    1.0|    1.0|    NaN|
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

And I would like to fillna depending on the value of the **created** column.

- If the month column is greater equal than the created value, then 1.0
- If the month column is less than the created value, then 0.0

The desired output should be:

```
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| user|created|month_1|month_2|month_3|month_4|
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  tom|      2|    0.0|    1.0|    1.0|    1.0|
| nick|      1|    1.0|    1.0|    1.0|    1.0|
| jack|      3|    0.0|    0.0|    1.0|    1.0|
|jason|      2|    0.0|    1.0|    1.0|    1.0|
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: are the non-null values always the same? what if some of them are greater and some of them are less than the created value?

Comment: The value of month column where the used was created is always non-null.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PySpark - Fillna specific rows based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57435380/pyspark-fillna-specific-rows-based-on-condition)

Comment: Not at all, because the columns to fill are different for every row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nanvl` to replace `NaN` with a conditional value created from `when`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.select(
    'user', 'created',
    *[
        F.nanvl(
            F.col(f'month_{c}'),
            F.when(F.col('created') <= c, 1).otherwise(0)
        ).alias(f'month_{c}')
        for c in range(1,5)
    ]
)

df2.show()
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| user|created|month_1|month_2|month_3|month_4|
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  tom|      2|    0.0|    1.0|    1.0|    1.0|
| nick|      1|    1.0|    1.0|    1.0|    1.0|
| jack|      3|    0.0|    0.0|    1.0|    1.0|
|jason|      2|    0.0|    1.0|    1.0|    1.0|
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```